# nosql and data organization

Tags: mongodb, nosql

So I'm writing an application that would allow a user to create a type of quiz.  Each quiz can be different, IE they will have unique questions and answers.  I've never played with any nosql database and I'm trying to wrap my head around how a nosql database (couch, mongo, etc...) actually organize the data.  It seems this kind of data storage might lend itself well to this type of application (IE no tables that define how many questions can be asked) but I'm still unsure of how a nosql database actually works.

I tend to be more of a visual learner, can anyone point me to some good visuals or describe how nosql databases actually organize the data they hold?

Comment: This seems like a situation where an SQL solution makes more sense. There's a defined structure for each represented object (questions, answers, users, etc.) which lends itself well to tables. Don't just apply the latest technology craze because it's there.

Comment: Also sounds as if you are not to hot on how sql db's work as it is quite easy to build tables to accomodate as many questions and as many answers to each question as you like with sql and actually less easy with say mongodb. I agree with Poly, bad idea to pick a technology and then apply it to a problem regardless and much better to analys the problem and then pick the best technology to solve it.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with these comments.  I actually been using  rdb's (mysql) for the last ten years.  I think they work great for many different things.  This is more of a learning project, and I want to see how things work so I can work out on my own what they would be good for.  It's going to be a node project, so it seemed like it would be an easy fit, json appeals to me.  But in regards to your comment, I whole heartedly agree.

Comment: These question, answers and comments are helping me in [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137258/local-sqlite-vs-remote-mongodb); thank's everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will talk about monogdb. Mongodb store her data in [bson](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/BSON) format (binary json). You can keep think that it store data in json format.

Mongodb contains one big benefit that you can use -- ability to [embedd](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating+Data+in+Mongo#UpdatingDatainMongo-EmbeddingDocumentsDirectlyinDocuments) documents. You can use this feature in your application:

So you can embedd  answers in your questions collection like this:

```
questions {
   _id: 1,
    text: "What is your name",
   answers: [
    {
      order: 1,
      text: "Andrew"
    },
   {
      order: 1,
      text: "Greg"
    }
   ]
}
```

Embedding usual keeps your database schema simpler and allow to avoid joins and data in general looks more naturally. For example in sql worlds you does not have any other solution as create separate tables for questions and answers.

Another benefit you may use is - scalability. Mongodb was designed to be fully scalable, it support sharding and replica sets.

You can start reading about schema desing more [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design). Also you can look into  [little monogdb book](http://openmymind.net/2011/3/28/The-Little-MongoDB-Book/), there only 30 pages, but it should help understand more deeply how mongodb works.

Just choose some nosql database and try to play with, you have fairly simple project to start with. And i am sure that you will love it once try.

Comment: The idea of working with json really appeals to me.  This is going to be a node project, so it seems they would work together really well.  So would the equivalent of a "users" table just be a user's object?  like users: [{id: 1, name: foo}, ...]  And then the quiz's object would just be quizzes: [{}, {}] with each entry being a unique quiz that's tied to some user's id?  In that way I see this being relational, but I know these types of db's get away from that concept...

Comment: "and most nosql databases in general" are document format. No. No. No. A number are key value pair and a number are big table based (like a spreadsheet) and indeed this is a major difference in the NoSQL arena in that they are not homogeneous and you really need to know what the problem is you are solving before you start coding so ytou an fit the data store to the problem. Document based OR Key Values Pairs OR Big Table and you need to understan CAP theorem and apply it to your problem as well to be able to make a rational decision.